# Cartoon with four or five characters with robot sidekicks. Protagonist fuses with sidekick to become a rock monster

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I recall watching a cartoon, with about four or five characters that had little robo-sidekicks (like bakugan) and the main character was really tan. He later fused together with his sidekick and became a rock monster thing.

One episode they battled weird clown, circus stuff but then became friends with them.

Comment: Off to a good start, but we could use some more details, can I suggest, if you haven't already, you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can edit in any more details?